# handler.post(runnable) doesnt always execute the run method in android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have created a Handler instance in the main ui thread(mUIHandler) and from a worker thread(other thread) when i am trying to execute the run method of the runnable the run method gets executed almost 9 out of 10 times but there is that 1 time when it doesn't get executed.

**mUIHandler.post(uiRunnable)** --> does it not always guarantee to execute the run method present in the runnable?

I even added log methods to check and could see that the logs till the post method innvocation gets executed but the run method logs don't get displayed.

How does the post(runnable) work internally? does it guarantee that the ui thread(thread with the handler) will excute this as soon as post is invoked?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @thinksteep will try to look into the suggestion given by mattc below to see if i could do something about it. I am avoiding posting the code snippet here as its more than 500 lines of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never seen a Handler not properly run the posted runnable. Some things to investigate:

1. Is there any logic that might result in a race condition between data the thread could be potentially interacting with while the UI-thread runnable is executing?
2. Do you have a try/catch anywhere that might be silently eating an exception?

My vote (without having seen your code) is that it's probably #1. You wouldn't be the first person to fall victim to hard-to-track-down race conditions as a result of concurrent logic.

Comment: Thanks Mattc for the answer i will cross check for a possible race condition.(Hope i could locate it.) Will update.

Comment: Thanks @Mattc it was the race condition which was doing it. Thankfully was able to find the cause. Indeed a good learning.

Comment: Glad you found it. Threaded logic is notoriously finicky and hard to debug.

Comment: Answer to this question might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548995/android-threading-and-handler-not-working This is what helped me, to create a single Handler in onCreate and then passed it around when needed.

Comment: Hi @MattC you say you never seen Handler that not properly  run posted runnable. Please take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444269/handler-post-execute-queue-not-in-correct-order) i added some test code there and it seems that the handler works not as expected.

Answer (score 12):

I've run into this problem as well on Android 2.2, in my case both Runnables and Messages were being used with the same Handler.

After looking at the Handler source code, it turns out that removing messages with a 'what' value of 0 also removes all queued Runnables. This happens because in the Handler class a Runnable is internally posted as a message with a 'what' value of zero, which are all removed by any call to `removeMessages(0)`. Therefore, avoid using zero as message id.

Comment: If only there could be two preferred answers. I have no idea how much time you saved me with this answer, but it's a lot of time!